# My website is accessed by direct URL but not by the domain name I bought. How to solve the issue?

Tags: php, jsp, dns, cpanel, web-hosting

I have bought hosting and domain name separately but later when Iam buying hosting I have linked hosting to the domain name I bought. Now after hosting all the files by uploading them to the CPanel 11 file manager the website is not coming live. Instead it is being redirected to some ww2."my domainname".com. But I can access my site by direct URL provided by the cpanel 11 hosting which is "mydomainname.md-48.webhostbox.net".

Comment: So, the problem is ?

Comment: You will have to ask the hosting company. There's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: What is your domain?

Comment: www.coachingfolks.com

Comment: I have submitted a request to hosting company. They are yet to reply

Comment: Correct your spilling mistakes. Delete from StackOverflow and move to SuperUser. This is completely unrelated to programming.

Comment: This question stays here till I find a solution. If its troubling you Mr. Muller then my apologies for that. If the moderators feel to remove it then I have no objection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see there is an issues with the Nameserver, You need to update your hosting server DNS to your domain register end and after that your domain prorogation may take 12-15 hours to propagate through all over internet

Comment: And how to do that in Cpanel 11?